# dynamic radio buttons as navigation not working until page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-radio

I have a bunch of radio buttons, in a popup, that use the below to show and hide related divs, thus allowing them to be used as a form of navigation.

```
   $(":radio[name='radio']").on("change", function () {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".radio").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    });
```

This works find when I load the page, the code is contained within the

```
$('#gameIndex').on('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
```

However I also want to be able to dynanically add new radio buttons - the divs the button point to already exist on the page.
I'm adding the buttons with:

```
$("#buttons").append('button code')
```

and then refreshing the div that contians the buttons with:

```
$("#radiodiv").trigger("create");
```

When I then trigger the popup with tte buttons they all appear as expected and are themed correctly. however when the buttons are clicked on they do nothing, they don't even seems to fire any kind of event. If I refesh the page they all start to work as expected.

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: You need to scope .on to an ancestor element present at invocation time

Comment: Could you put it up in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current change binding:

```
$(":radio[name='radio']").on("change", function () {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $(".radio").hide();
    $("#" + test).show();
});
```

will not work retroactively on newly added elements, you need to use a delegated event binding for it to work:

```
$(document).on('change', ':radio[name="radio"]',function () {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $(".radio").hide();
    $("#" + test).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:
[Refrence](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)
    `$(":radio[name='radio']").live("change", function() { 
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".radio").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    });`